# How do I enter a URL in genymotion simulator

Tags: selenium, appium, genymotion

I am working on `Appium` and `Genymotion` in automating a mobile web page.

I could open the browser in Genymotion from the desired capabilities by passing
`browserName=Browser` and then how do I enter my website URL in the browser.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I can't seem to find the question in your post.

Answer (score 1):

You can navigate to any URL just like you do with browsers in desktop, using Selenium WebDriver.

For reference you can check this piece of code:

I am assuming that you have created the instance of WebDriver  , lets say - driver

```
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(url_and_port_in_which_appium_server_started), capabilities);
```

Following is the code to navigate to the desired URL

```
driver.get("http://www.google.co.in");
```

or

```
driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");
```